How to convert string date from 2022/11/05 to 2022-11-05
How to replace slash to dash in date string
Replace / to -
From
2022/12/05
To
2022-12-05
How to convert string date from 2022/11/05 to 2022-11-05

.Replace("/", "-")?

Or, parse the string to a DateTime and then format it as a date string in the format you desire. It's a more robust (and likely maintainable) solution

"From
2022/12/05
To
2022/12/05" Please fix this

Why you want to replace the slash to a dash? Sounds like an xy problem. Either you want to do that because you need it in an sql query, then better use parameterized queries and and don't pass strings to the db but datetime. Or you want to do that because you think that you need it for parsing it to Date. Then better use the overload with the correct culture like Date.Parse("2022/12/05", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Where did the original string come from?

Please do not tag spam. You're using either C# or VB.Net, not both simultaneously. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and should not be abused. Tag spamming is a very quick way to get your post downvoted and/or closed. You'll find your experiences here will be much better if you take the time to go through the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how the site works before you begin posting.

Also, repeating the same content or adding noise to bypass the minimum length requirements is a violation of the site guidelines, as well as being an insult to the millions of users who ask or answer questions here. If you can't be bothered to ask the question properly, why should it be worth our effort to answer it?

Consider using Replace:
Module Program
    Sub Main()
        Dim dateString As String = "2022/12/05"
        Dim newDateString As String = dateString.Replace("/", "-")
        Console.WriteLine("Original Date: " & dateString)
        Console.WriteLine("Modified Date: " & newDateString)
    End Sub
End Module

Output:
Original Date: 2022/12/05
Modified Date: 2022-12-05

Try on godbolt.org

Alternatively, you can parse the string to a DateTime and then format it as a date string in the format you desire since it's a more robust (and likely maintainable) solution:
Imports System

Module Program
    Sub Main()
        Dim dateString As String = "2022/12/05"
        Try
            Dim dateValue As DateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy/MM/dd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
            Dim formattedDate As String = dateValue.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
            Console.WriteLine("Formatted Date: " & formattedDate)
        Catch ex As FormatException
            Console.WriteLine("The date string is not in a valid format.")
        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine("An unexpected error occurred: " & ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Module

Output:
Formatted Date: 2022-12-05

Try on godbolt.org
